# How to display text content onclick of listview item

Tags: android

I want to display a product detail page on click of a product name from list view.And for this i dont want to display in dialog alert. It should be new screen for product detail page.

based on clicked product name how can i show the product detail screen. Any ideas ?

can you pl help on this.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Do you want to display the Text in a `WebView`, based on which entry the user selected in your `ListView`? If not, please be more specific.

Comment: If i use webview, is it possible to provide next and previous icons in product detail page ? so that whenever user clicks on next icon it will navigate to next product details page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted, I have the following solution in mind:

- Your `ListActivity` contains all the
  products you have.
- If you click on one of those
  products, a new Activity is launched
  which provides more informations
  about the product (for example in a
  `WebView`).

The "next" and "previous"-buttons you describe would be placed on this Activity, too.

I guess all your product informations are stored in an SQLiteDatabase? If so, every product should have an ID which can be used the find the "next"- and "previous"-products in your `Show`-Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't super clear.  However, if you're just trying to display some information, trying using Toast.  Toast displays a small "dialog" containing a message you can define.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear, actually i want to display a product detail page on click of a product name from list view. And i dont want the detail page as dialog with message.It would be new screen with product detail information